# Is it possible to edit field values in DBGrid connected to a dataset from a FULL JOIN table SELECT query?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2000

I have this query

```
SELECT
   T1.Add,
   T1.Edit,
   T1.Usr,
   T2.FirstName,
   T2.LastName 
FROM
   T2 
FULL JOIN 
   T1 ON T1.Usr = T2.Guid
```

Is it possible to edit this result from DBGrid ?
I want to add Fields `T1.Add` and `T1.Edit` to `T1` table 
if they are not already there
and change their values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the used components you could use BeforePost (doing your actions and requery), ModifySQL/insertSQL for IBDataSet, OpdateObject TQuery, etc.
Another way would by using " INSTEAD OF triggers" for a persitant view.